# Python context manager: enter only once

Tags: python, python-asyncio, contextmanager

I have a context manager class that sets up a TCP connection in its **aenter** routine. Now this class is also a singleton, and when it gets used by several clients, it should not set up the connection twice as it is already up.

```
class TcpConnector(self):
    async def __aenter__(self):
      await set_up_tcp_connection()
      return self
    
    async def read_value(self): ...
    
    @classmethod:
    def get_instance(cls):
      if cls.__instance:
        return cls.__instance
      return cls()

class Client(self):
  def start(self):
    provider = TcpConnector.get_instance()
    with provider as conn:
      while True:
        print(await conn.read_value())

tasks = [
Client().start(),
Client().start()  # will set up the connection a second time
]
await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Is there a good pattern for this, or should I just use my context manager before instantiating the clients, and pass it to the start() function?

e.g.:

```
provider = TcpConnector.get_instance()
with provider as conn:
  tasks = [
    Client().start(provider),
    Client().start(provider)
  ]

await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: I would go the second route; it's more explicit about the connection being shared by multiple clients. Given that `provider` and `conn` are the same object, you can simply write `with TcpConnecter() as provider: tasks = [...]`. I think you're putting unnecessary emphasis on having only one instance of `TcpConnector` at a time. (There's a difference between "I only expect to need one instance" and "The world is going to explode if a second instance is created.")

Comment: in this case, I have to make sure I only ever open a single TCP connection, so it is important that only one instance be created and that it does not set up multiple connections. BUt I realised I can probably verify whether the connection is set up in `__aenter__` and return `self` if it is.

Comment: All the more reason to distinguish between who *opens* the connection and who *uses* that connection.